# Validation Rule for Checkbox

Tags: validation-rule

If I check the box for Hard Start, I should be able to input data into the Hard Start Time.  If data is entered in the Hard Start Time without the Hard Start being checked an error should appear.  What validation rule should I use to confirm?

Comment: Just curious as to the purpose of the checkbox. If needed for reports, etc why not just check it if a date/time is entered. If it is there to provide another step the user must do to confirm the date time entry then I would review the need. Just some thoughts....

Answer (score 1):

In general, you want to ensure that a checkbox field is checked if a certain Date/Time field has a value.  In order to do that you would do something like this.

```
AND(
    Checkbox_Field__c = false,
    NOT(ISBLANK(Date_Time_Field__c))
)
```